# jQuery: using a loop to create many elements with images and html

Tags: javascript, html

I have a loop like this:

```
for (i = 0; i < number; i++) {
     // retrieve several pieces of information each time which will be result[0], result[1] etc.
     p = document.createElement('p')
     p.className = 'box'
     p.innerHTML = '<img src="http://website.com/1.png" width="80%" height="100%"</a>' + result[0] + '<h5> more html etc... </h5>'
     maintable.appendChild(p) 
}
```

I need the image to change according to the value if `i` (be `website.com/1.png` for `i=0`, `website.com/2.png` for `i=1` etc) and append HTML after that which will include the `result[0]`, `result[1]` etc. that the loop fetches.

I have tried adding an `id` to the image and then doing `('#id').attr('src', 'http://website.com/' + (i + 1) + '.png')` at the end of the loop, but this isn't working as intended. I've also tried using `p.append` for everything I need to add (instead of one `innerHTML`), but this is ignoring HTML eg. `p.append("<h5>Object #1</h5>")` will show the h5 tag on the page.

I have looked at answers for adding multiple images through a loop but haven't got them to work in this specific case.

How should this best be done?

Comment: can you share your code on jsfiddle

Comment: The generated markup is invalid: `<img src="http://website.com/1.png" width="80%" height="100%"</a>...<h5> more html etc... </h5>`

Comment: @HassanImam It still won't do what you think it should do.

Comment: Use this `p.innerHTML = '<img src="http://website.com/" (i+1) + ".png" width="80%" height="100%" ><span>' + result[i] + '</span><h5> more html etc... </h5>'`, I hope this will work. @Andreas

Comment: @HassanImam Nope...

Comment: What is still wrong @Andreas ?

Comment: @HassanImam What about testing it yourself?

Comment: @Andreas is it about `"` ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think your problem is the (i+1). This turns your expression into an integer. Just use i with no math expression. I tried this

```
p.innerHTML = '<img src="http://hippopool.com/media/'+i+'.jpg" width="600" height="100"><h5>more html etc</h5>';
```

And don't forget to terminate your javascript lines with semicolon.

Comment: looks like that's all it was

Answer (score 0):

you can create image like as below and set value

```
var imgurl = 'http://website.com/' + (i + 1) + '.png';
var img = $('<img id="dynamic">');
img.attr('src', imgurl);
img.appendTo('#imagediv');///append image to given element id
//here in this case it get append to div which is having id `imagediv`
```

Comment: Why should he use jQuery for such a basic task? And where is the rest of the generated markup?

Comment: @Andreas - why shouldent ? jquery is easy and he is already tagged question with jquery and migh be he is using that also ...i can provide full working code , but i dont know his mark up and if you see in question i asked him to provide code in jsfiddle

Answer (score 0):

```
for (i = 0; i < number; i++) {
    var x = "";
     // retrieve several pieces of information each time which will be result[0], result[1] etc.
     var img = document.createElement('img');
     maintable.appendChild(img);
      img.setAttribute("class", "box");
      if (i % 5 == 0){
        x = "image1.png";
      }
      else if(i % 5 == 1){
        x = "image2.png";
      }
      else if(i % 5 == 2){
        x = "image3.png";
      }
      else if(i % 5 == 3){
        x = "image4.png";
      }
      else if(i % 5 == 4){
        x = "image5.png";
      }

      img.setAttribute("src", x);
}
```

You cannot assign paragraph elements image properties, you have to create the image element. This code changes the image between five images.

Comment: He's trying to create more than an image in the loop. And why the if-else block?

Comment: The if and else blocks are used because he said he wanted five different image.

Comment: The only 5 in the question is from the `<h5>` tag